# Execute PHP script in console in foreground

Tags: php, shell, cmd, terminal

I have a script from where i try to call another script by using `shell_exec()`:

**test.php**

```
$webroot = getcwd();
shell_exec("php $webroot/myscript.php");
```

**myscript.php**

```
<?php
echo "hello";
```

I want `myscript.php` to open in a console. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you use `shell_exec` if you want just open myscript.php in console?) >php myscript.php

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible. I try to debug something.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is to run the script in GTK terminal . What you can do is something like this

```
$webroot = getcwd();
shell_exec("xterm -hold -e 'php $webroot/myscript.php'");
```

this will pop open a terminal and hold it until the user closes the same. This is for linux only.

Comment: Is there also a solution for windows?

Comment: @EdwardBlack windows uses powershell as terminal so you can have a look at that and see how to execute command in powershell and hold the output. Unluckily i don't use windows so can't be sure of the command but the procedure remains the same

Answer (score 0):

You can. Your example is working.

You can look output from `shell_exec` in test.php:

```
$webroot = getcwd();
$output = shell_exec("php $webroot/myscript.php");
echo $output;
```

Comment: This won't pop up a console.